# e4x newb woes - attribute trace

Tags: javascript, xml, e4x

Sorry if I'm doing anything really dumb, but could anybody see anything immediately wrong with the following?

```
var layout = new XML()

layout=
<layout color="red">
</layout>

function init()
{ 
post(layout.@color);
}
```

it returns what I assume to be a ram address rather than the value.

In the event that the software in question wants an object of type string, what is the best way to enforce that? I doubt thats the cas, but am willing to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string cast should work fine, e.g.:

```
trace(String(layout.@color));
```

Note that in your example there's no need to assign a new XML object to `layout`, since you overwrite it with the next assignment one line later.

[This article](http://dispatchevent.org/roger/as3-e4x-rundown/) is highly useful if you're just getting started with E4X.

Comment: To my total shock, this actually worked. Software in question is Max/msp, a signal processing environment (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max/msp). Thats also where the post method comes from btw. Thanks so much, now I actually feel better aboput my OOP powers.